# Automatic detection of domain for dependent type function in Idris

Tags: functional-programming, dependent-type, idris, injective-function

Idris language tutorial has simple and understandable example of the idea of *Dependent Types*: 
http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#first-class-types

Here is the code:

```
isSingleton : Bool -> Type
isSingleton True = Int
isSingleton False = List Int

mkSingle : (x : Bool) -> isSingleton x
mkSingle True = 0
mkSingle False = []

sum : (single : Bool) -> isSingleton single -> Int
sum True x = x
sum False [] = 0
sum False (x :: xs) = x + sum False xs
```

I decided to spend more time on this example. What bothers me in `sum` function is that I need to explicitly pass `single : Bool` value to function. I don't want to do this and I want compiler to guess what this boolean value should be. Hence I pass only `Int` or `List Int` to `sum` function there should be 1-to-1 correspondence between boolean value and type of argument (if I pass some other type this just mustn't type check).

Of course, I understand, this is not possible in general case. Such compiler tricks require my function `isSingleton` (or any other similar function) be ***injective***. But for this case it should be possible as it seems to me...

So I started with next implementation: I just made `single` argument implicit.

```
sum : {single : Bool} -> isSingleton single -> Int
sum {single = True} x = x
sum {single = False} [] = 0
sum {single = False} (x :: xs) = x + sum' {single = False} xs
```

Well, it doesn't really solve my problem because I still need to call this function in the next way:

`sum {single=True} 1`

But I read in tutorial about `auto` keyword. Though I don't quite understand what `auto` does (because I didn't find description of it) I decided to patch my function just a little bit more:

```
sum' : {auto single : Bool} -> isSingleton single -> Int
sum' {single = True} x = x
sum' {single = False} [] = 0
sum' {single = False} (x :: xs) = x + sum' {single = False} xs
```

And it works for lists!

```
*DepFun> :t sum'
sum' : {auto single : Bool} -> isSingleton single -> Int
*DepFun> sum' [1,2,3]
6 : Int
```

But doesn't work for single value :(

```
*DepFun> sum' 3
When checking an application of function Main.sum':
        List Int is not a numeric type
```

Can someone explain is it actually possible to achieve my goal in such injective function usages currently? I watched this short video about proving something is injective: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ml8u7DFgAk

But I don't understand how I can use such proofs in my example.
If this is not possible what is the best way to write such functions?

Comment: It looks like Idris doesn't really infer anything here, it just uses the default value for booleans (`False`). Redefine the functions, swapping `True` and `False`, and you'll see that `sum' 3` works, but `sum' [1,2,3]` doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `auto` keyword basically tells Idris, "Find me any value of this type". So you're liable to get the wrong answer unless that type only contains one value. Idris sees `{auto x : Bool}` and fills it in with any old `Bool`, namely `False`. It doesn't use its knowledge of later arguments to help it choose - information doesn't flow from right to left.

One fix would be to make the information flow in the other direction. Rather using a universe-style construction as you have above, write a function accepting an arbitrary type and use a predicate to refine it to the two options you want. This way Idris can look at the type of the preceding argument and pick the only value of `IsListOrInt` whose type matches.

```
data IsListOrInt a where
    IsInt : IsListOrInt Int
    IsList : IsListOrInt (List Int)

sum : a -> {auto isListOrInt : IsListOrInt a} -> Int
sum x {IsInt} = x
sum [] {IsList} = 0
sum (x :: xs) {IsList} = x + sum xs
```

Now, in this case the search space is small enough (two values - `True` and `False`) that Idris could feasibly explore every option in a brute-force fashion and pick the first one that results in a program which passes the type checker, but that algorithm doesn't scale well when the types are much bigger than two, or when trying to infer multiple values.

Compare the left-to-right nature of the information flow in the above example with the behaviour of regular non-`auto` braces, which instruct Idris to find the result in a *bidirectional* fashion using unification. As you note, this could only succeed when the type functions in question are injective. You could structure your input as a separate, indexed datatype, and allow Idris to look at the constructor to find `b` using unification.

```
data OneOrMany isOne where
    One : Int -> OneOrMany True
    Many : List Int -> OneOrMany False

sum : {b : Bool} -> OneOrMany b -> Int
sum (One x) = x
sum (Many []) = 0
sum (Many (x :: xs)) = x + sum (Many xs)

test = sum (One 3) + sum (Many [29, 43])
```

Predicting when the machine will or won't be able to guess what you mean is an important skill in dependently-typed programming; you'll find yourself getting better at it with more experience.

Of course, in this case it's all moot because lists already have one-or-many semantics. Write your function over plain old lists; then if you need to apply it to a single value you can just wrap it in a singleton list.

Comment: Thanks! I agree that approach with `One` or `Many` is better but it is even better to not overcomplicate things in such simple examples.